# AMQP connection refused on 2.13.1 but working on 2.13.0

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, amqp

I'm updating a Quarkus application that uses reactive AMQP messaging connector with a customized underlying Vert.x client, SSL and client certificate authentication (as explained in https://quarkus.io/guides/amqp-reference#customizing-the-underlying-amqp-client).

Up to 2.13.0.Final it's working and connecting to the AMQP broker, but from 2.13.1.Final it's unable to connect to the broker due to connection refused.

I checked release notes and diffs: there is a Vert.x update from 4.3.3 to 4.3.4 (with changes as https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-amqp-client/pull/80/commits/8d92ddb543f7df5f9925730f452bf2d5713161ce), but I don’t understand what impacts they can have on my code.

Comment: I would recommend to submit a small reproducer in an issue on the GH repo of Quarkus.